# How to measure the download and upload speed from my PC to a website?

Tags: uploading, download

There is an upload function on a website and I want to measure the upload and download speeds from my PC to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way, download a 10MB/100MB file from here:
http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test or http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test and save on your PC.

Then just time the upload/download to the website in question.

Say you use the 10MB and it takes 70 seconds to upload. Then the speed is 10/70 = 0.142857 MB/s = 146.2857 KB/s

Answer (score 0):

If you just need anecdotal numbers, not exact rates, you can use the built-into Windows 7 "Resource Monitor" ([5 Ways to Monitor and Improve Windows 7 Performance](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/07/29/5-ways-to-monitor-and-improve-windows-7-performance/)). Linux has the rrdtool ([Network Traffic Monitoring with RRDTool](http://martybugs.net/linux/rrdtool/traffic.cgi)).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a bandwidth monitor (e.g.: [DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about), for Windows).